# Selecting the digits in a specific section inside a string

Tags: php

I want to pick digits between other groups of digits.

I think it is best that I show this pattern in order to explain what I mean:

```
xxxxx...xxxxyyyyyyy....yyyyzzzzzzz....zzzz
{   1000   }               {     1500    }
```

So from the above string structure, I want to pick the digits that occur between the first 1000 digits (xx) and the final 1500 digits (zz).

I tried `substr` but as I have to specify the length it didn't work for me. Because I don't know what the length is between those two indexes.

Here is my code:

```
$id = base64_encode($core->security(1070).$list["user_id"]);
```

`$core->security` creates number as many as what is input.
In this it example it creates a length of 1070 random digits.

```
$decoded = base64_decode($id);
$homework_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,substr($decoded, 1070));
```

I can pick numbers after some length of digits. But I want to take them *between* series of digits.

Comment: Please share some code, what you expect given specific inputs, and your current attempts.

Comment: I don't understand what `base64_decode` and `mysqli_real_escape_string` have to do with your question?

Comment: I did a major update of your question to make it clearer. Could you verify it is as you wanted it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried `substr` but as I have to specify the length it didnt work for me. Because I don't the length between 1000 number and 1500 number.

There is a feature of `substr` that you might have missed. From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

> If `length` is given and is negative, then that many characters will be omitted from the end of string

So this would work:

```
$left = 1000;  // Number of characters to be chopped off from the left side
$right = 1500; // Number of characters to be chopped off from the right side
$id = substr($id, $left, -$right) ?: "";
```

The `?: ""` part is there to convert `false` to `""`. `substr` will return `false` when there are not enough characters present in the string to chop off that many characters. If in that case you just want to get an empty string, then `?: ""` will do just that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [regex](https://regex101.com/r/fsp3FS/14) to capture numbers that is between `1000` and `1500`

```
<?php
 $number = '10001212121212121500'; #make it string first
 if (preg_match('/1000(.*?)1500/', $number, $match) == 1) {
  echo (int)$match[1];
 }
?>
```

**DEMO1:** https://3v4l.org/pebul

**DEMO2:** https://3v4l.org/8TiWH

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = <<<HEREDOC
xxxxx...xxxxyyyyyyy....yyyyzzzzzzz....zzzz
{   1000   }               {     1500    }
HEREDOC;

preg_match_all('/\{\s+(\d+)\s+\}/', $text, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "{   1000   }"
    [1]=>
    string(15) "{     1500    }"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "1000"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "1500"
  }
}
```